# What's the difference between list.append(a[:]) and list.append(a) in python?

Tags: python, list

This is related to leetcode problem #39.
I started with `results.append(solution)`, which does not append properly to the list, and found in the solution that `results.append(solution[:])` works. What's the difference between these two syntax?

```
class Solution:
def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    results=[]
    def backtracking(candidates,target,start,solution,results):
        #print(start,target,solution,results)
        if target<0:
            return
        if target==0:
            results.append(solution[:])
            return

        for i in range(start,len(candidates)):
            solution.append(candidates[i])
            backtracking(candidates,target-candidates[i],i,solution,results)
            solution.pop()


    backtracking(candidates,target,0,[],results)
    return results
```

Comment: `a[:]` is a shallow copy of `a`, `list.append(a)` you are just adding `a` into the list.

Comment: [how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[:]` will create a new list.
`c.append(b)` appends the list `b` to `c`.

Following code will help understand this better -

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5]
>>> c=[1,2,3]
>>> a.append(b) #append b
>>> c.append(b[:]) #create new list and append
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
>>> b
[4, 5]
>>> a[3][0]=99 #modify a
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [99, 5]] #a modified
>>> b
[99, 5] #so does b
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]] #modify c
>>> c[3][1]=99
>>> c #c modified
[1, 2, 3, [4, 99]]
>>> b #original b did not get modified
[99, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `id` of the objects, making a slice creates a new list

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
2711680383816
>>> id(a[:])
2711683338696
```

whereas assigning the list directly refers to the same object

```
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
2711680383816
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a list and `a[:]` is a new list with all elements copied.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a == a[:]
True
>>> a is a[:]
False
```

Let's have another list `b = ["a", "b"]`. `append` adds whatever you give it to the end of a list. If you append another list, the *reference* to that list gets added and might lead to un expected behaviours:

```
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
["a", "b", [1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[0] = "c"
>>> b
["a", "b", ["c", 2, 3]]
>>> b[2][1] = 42
>>> a
["c", 42, 3]
>>> a is b[2]
True
```

You can see, that after appending `a`, if you change an element in `a`, it also changes in `b`. This is because `b` only has a *reference* to `a`. To prevent that, you can instead do `b.append(a[:])`. This will *copy* the values in `a`, so when you then change values in `a`, values in `b` stay what they were when you copied them:

```
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
["a", "b", [1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[0] = "c"
>>> b
["a", "b", [1, 2, 3]]
>>> b[2][1] = 42
>>> a
["c", 2, 3]
>>> a is b[2]
False
```

So in your question, using `solution[:]` makes sure that whatever has been added to the `results` doesn't change when `solution.append` happens on the next iteration of the `for` loop.